# How to implement Auditing system in C# in webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, coding-style, repository-pattern

I created a webservice for my application. In that webservice i'm accessing SQL server for Datas. Now the feature, i've to implement is, i have to check some table at some time and based the value i need to notify customer.  I can achieve this by implementing new controller(i already have controller for views). Now my question is,  will this break any standard structure? 
Is there pattern i should follow for including this type of feature to application? 
  Stackoverflow must have multiple service for their rewarding system and notification system. They also did like this? if there is any better approach please let me know.

Comment: sorry if my question wasn't clear enough,, the actual requirement is, i need to know the best approach/pattern for including auditing system to existing application..

Answer (score 4):

You can user [signalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) to send notifications from server to client or multiple clients.

Comment: sorry if my question wasn't clear enough,, the actual requirement is, i need to know the best approach/pattern for including auditing system to existing application..

Comment: You have 2 approaches. 1. Polling, client check server every minute (like when you check mail) 2. Push, server have a possibility to send messages to user.

Comment: You have to choose between this tow approaches, it depends on how many messages every client will have, and how many users you will have  simultaneously in your service.